# How to catch runtime exception in bytecode through ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to catch runtime exception through exception. I am able to capture usual method exiting events. 
But , the control never reaches in `opcode==Opcodes.ATHROW` .

I think I am doing something wrong in calling the events.

Here is my sample code :

```
 public void visitCode() { 
//          mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"); 
//          mv.visitLdcInsn("Entering method "  + fQMethodName); 
//          mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream","println","(Ljava/lang/String;)V"); 
            }


     @Override
    public void visitInsn(int opcode)
    {



         if (opcode == Opcodes.ATHROW)
         {
                          mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "err", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");

          mv.visitLdcInsn("Exiting on exception " );         
             mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
         }


        super.visitInsn(opcode);
    }


         public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name,
                   String desc) {


                  super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);
                    //                
                  if (opcode == Opcodes.ATHROW)
                  {
                                              mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "err", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");

                   mv.visitLdcInsn("Exiting on exception " + name);         
                      mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println",
                            "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
                  }
                  else if (!name.equals("println")
                    && !name.equals("<init>")
                    && (opcode == Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL || opcode == Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL
                      || opcode == Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC || opcode == Opcodes.INVOKEDYNAMIC)) {




                      this.currentMethod = name;

                   onFinally(opcode);
                  }
                 }

                 private void onFinally(int opcode) {
                                          mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "err",
                    "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
                  mv.visitLdcInsn("Returning to " + fQMethodName + " from " + currentMethod);
                  mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
                 }
```

At the time of runtime exception , the existing stack content is cleared and only the throwable object remains. Can I get the stack top element ( i.e stack frame basically ) through ASM ?

Thanks in adavance.

**EDIT :**

Here is my modified program after adding try - catch block.

@Holger : Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.

So , I am trying to insert dynamic try-catch block in MethodVisitor of ASM.

Here is my code :

```
public void visitCode() 
    {

        super.visitCode();

        this.visitTryCatchBlock(lblTryBlockStart, lblTryBlockEnd, lblCatchExceptionBlockStart, "java/lang/Exception");
        this.visitLabel(lblTryBlockStart);

    }  



    public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals)
    {
        // visit try block end label
        this.visitLabel(lblTryBlockEnd);
        // visit normal execution exit block
        this.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, exitBlock);

        // visit catch exception block
        this.visitLabel(lblCatchExceptionBlockStart);
        // store the exception
        this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, 1);
        // load the exception
        this.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 1);
        // call printStackTrace()
        //this.visitInsn(Opcodes.ATHROW);
        this.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Exception", "printStackTrace", "()V");


        // exit from this dynamic block
        this.visitLabel(exitBlock);

        super.visitMaxs(maxStack+2, maxLocals+2);

    }
```

My intention is to add dynamic try - catch block , and if any exception is thrown , print it.

Comment: Do you know where the actual RuntimeException is thrown? If it's thrown by the JRE itself this won't work since (i'm guessing) you're not transforming classes in the java package (which you shouldn't be doing anyway).

Comment: Your latest update is working? I too wanted to add try catch block in a method. Please respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RuntimeException`s do not need an `athrow` instruction to be thrown. An `idiv` or `irem` instruction can throw an `ArithmeticException`, a `getfield`, `putfield` or `invoke…` instruction can throw a `NullPointerException`, just to name some examples. So you don’t find an athrow instruction at these places.

The only way to intercept all of them is to inject an exception handler which processes your code, and re-throws the exception if you wish.

Comment: I have added `Label` statements and visited them. And I have also tried `visitTryCatchBlock` method. But , after that I could not proceed further. Can you please help me a little bit in this ?

Comment: Is it correct ?`mv.visitTryCatchBlock(lTryBlockStart, lTryBlockEnd, lCatchBlockStart, "java/lang/Exception");
  super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc);            
  mv.visitLabel(lTryBlockEnd);                
 mv.visitJumpInsn(org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.GOTO,lCatchBlockEnd);
  mv.visitLabel(lCatchBlockStart);
  mv.visitVarInsn(org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ASTORE, 1); 
  mv.visitVarInsn(org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ALOAD, 1);   mv.visitMethodInsn(org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Exception", "printStackTrace", "()V");
  mv.visitLabel(lCatchBlockEnd);
  
 }`

Comment: This goes beyond the scope of comments; I recommend opening a new question for this.

Comment: You wrote what you have done but you didn’t tell what your problem with this code is.

Comment: I want to capture the exception with its full stacktrace. Right now , my problem is that - I can not capture the exception object. I am able to do `this.visitInsn(Opcodes.ATHROW)` . But , I am not able store it.. I am doing `this.visitInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE,1)` , but I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You should work on your problem descriptions. What does “I am not able store it” mean? Anyway, your sequence must be `astore_1` `aload_1` `invokevirtual (printStackTrace)` `aload_1` `athrow`. See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion , will definitely keep in mind . Now coming to the problem , I want to pass the exception to one of my written method which takes exception as an argument , so I have to call `visitLdcInsn` , right ? This is where I am stuck

Comment: `ldc` has nothing to do with invoking methods. If your method is `public static void exceptionOccurred(Throwable) {}` in a class `foo.Bar` then just do `aload_1` to put the argument on the stack followed by `visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "foo/Bar", "exceptionOccurred", "(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38051/discussion-between-shounak-kundu-and-holger)

Comment: @Holger, I am getting this error. JSR/RET are not supported in computeFrame option. Any suggestions?